# How do I set up Jupyter notebook on a linux server (RHEL7) for my team to use via Chrome browser?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, redhat

I am leading a team of analysts and want to introduce them to Jupyter Notebook as a window into Python programming.

We have Anaconda downloaded and installed on our Linux server. I've asked our IT to help set it up to run on Google Chrome and they have been able to only provide the following steps:

1. source /R_Data/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

this kicks off Anaconda on the server, must run in PUTTY. We stored the installation in the same location as RStudio hence the R_Data in the filepath.

2. /R_Data/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8889

This sets up the port 8889 with a token generated each time from scratch. We then need to grab the token id and paste into Chrome with the full URL per step 3

3. http://localhost:8889/?token=ea97e502a7f45d....

When I paste this in Chrome it loads Jupyter.

While this gets the job done it seems less than ideal for an entire team of analysts to have to do this each time. We also have RStudio installed on the same server but that simply opens from Chrome using a URL since I assume it is always running in the background. Jupyter and Anaconda seem to only run once they are kicked off first in PUTTY and I would like a way to bypass those steps.

I am familiar with the Jupyter config file however my limited understanding as a non-developer tells me it applies only to each user and cannot be applied to all users simultaneously (i.e. as a root user on the server or something to that effect).

I am hoping someone here might point me in the right direction. I should also point out that as a Redhat user I can't follow instructions based in Ubuntu since that syntax seems different.

Many thanks for the help.
Yoni

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way is to run `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=12345` on your server while connecting through the ssh tunel as `ssh -N -f -L 12345:localhost:12345 myserveralias`. Now jupyter is on your 12345 localhost. Things like AutoSSH or Keep Alive will help with an erratic network, however, take security into account.